Shooting helicopter through glass elevator
Action movie I think. Somewhere near the beginning of the movie someone is in one of those elevators with outward facing windows so one can see a panoramic vista open before them as the elevator ascends. As the lift nears the top a helicopter rises menacingly in front of it, hovering.  Then the person in the lift pulls out a gun and starts firing through the window at the chopper.  After a few seconds of this the chopper turns and descends rapidly, possibly out of control.
What was the title of this movie?
Edit: additional details - American movie, I would say late 80s, but possible that it was a bit later. The shooter might have been a fairly well know 'action' star.

Do you have any more details that may help identification? When did you see it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Anything else you might remember, however insignificant it may seem to you.

The parts that I recall most clear are the elevator ascending, the helicopter hovering, the shooter firing several rounds before the helicopter suddenly turns and moves away in obvious distress, and possibly a catchy "dodododo" music theme as the helicopter turns away.  The clips I have found for Last Action Hero don't seem to match this.  It's possible I am remembering a clip from a game based on the movie, or just have a faulty memory.  I'm looking for the full scene from Last Action Hero to watch before I rule it out.

Actually "dodododo" isn't very descriptive.  I meant to say I seem to recall 4 or 5 notes, all ascending or descending or ascending (don't recall which) and then this sequence repeated maybe 2-3 times.

I remember a very similar scene from Last Action Hero:

Young Danny Madigan is a big fan of Jack Slater, a larger-than-life
  action hero played by Arnold Schwarzenegger. When his best friend,
  Nick the projectionist, gives him a magic ticket to the new Jack
  Slater film, Danny is transported into Slater's world, where the good
  guys always win. One of Slater's enemies, Benedict the hitman, gets
  hold of the ticket and ends up in Danny's world, where he realises
  that if he can kill Schwarzenegger, Slater will be no more. Slater and
  Danny must travel back and stop him.

In one scene Arnie (or rather Jack) fights a helicopter just with his guns from the top and inside of an external glass elevator (and wins, I think). But it isn't near the beginning of the movie but more in the middle.

That scene (though so far I only have a teaser clip) looks different enough from what I remember that I'm not sure it's the same scene (or maybe my memory is faulty) - but it does star Schwarzenegger and I was vaguely thinking he or a similar actor like Willis or Stallone or such was the character shooting at the chopper.

I've finally had a chance to find and watch the relevant clip from the movie, and it's not what I remember.  Maybe it was the Last Action Hero pinball game with a clip roughly based on the movie?

The more I think about it, I'm pretty sure it was a different movie, maybe with a short name.  What movie was the elevator scene in Last Action Hero spoofing or modelled on?  That might be the movie I am looking for.
